# TypeScript not complaining about properties that do not exist when using spread operator

Tags: typescript

I have a issue that when using a spread operator in Typescript the compiler won't complain that the property you change does not exist. An simple example would be this:

```
interface Car {
    name: string,
    price: number
}

const redCar = <Car>{ name: 'redCar', price: 25.000 };
const changePrice = <Car>{ ...redCar, pric: 20.000 };
```

In the above example the compiler does complain when you would incorrectly type price when assigning it to redCar but when using the spreadOperator, it does not complain that it does not exist. I do know that you can do the following:

```
interface Car {
    name: string,
    price: number
}
    
const redCar: Car = { name: 'redCar', price: 25.000 };
const changePrice: Car = { ...redCar, pric: 20.000 };
```

But I don't every time create a variable (for example when using a map) when adjusting variables inside a object. Is there a certain rule which I need to enable to prevent such errors from happening?

Comment: [TSC is complaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJysg3gKGf5EOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwBo8CAHWpCkAV2ICNocAXxw4EAexDVkUCABN0mALzIAPAoB8WQiXLIA5DPkY9DZG2AdkAJgCsAOgAMT5IIDcoiVIQALOCDoQAArsKMpqGJrIdtGGCqbmCBRWDo7ObiIEyB6SYNJyClYUCsjKWkSkFAb5xvEhSfZODi7u4jnIPn4BwRYQhWgYJdhRMdVQtRZJKY3NQA)

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler it is complaining for the second one but not the first one. I want that it also complains for the first one. Now this can happen: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJysg3gKGf5EOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwBo8CAHWpCkAV2ICNocAXxw4EAexDVkUCABN0mALzIAPAoB8WQiXLIA5DPkY9DZG2AdkAJgCsAOgAMT5IIDcoiVIQALOCDoQAArsKMpqGJrIdtGGCqbmCBRWDo7ObiLikmIANhB22WJ0ABQ+fgHBFhAAlO5AA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent excess properties you can use `satifies` available from TS 4.9 onwards.

```
interface Car {
    name: string,
    price: number
}

const redCar = { name: 'redCar', price: 25.000 } satisfies Car;
const changePrice = { ...redCar, pric: 20.000 } satisfies Car;

console.log(changePrice);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJysg3gKGf5EOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwBo8CAHWpCkAV2ICNocAXxw4EAexDVkUCABN0mALzZCJcsgDkM%20Rg0NkbYB2QAmAKwA6AAw3kgqnDDBKMYBEpoMAblESpCAAs4EDoIAAV2FGUsZAs47QV9QwQKEytrW3tKR2dXd08oH19JMQAbCAtSsToACkDg0IijCABKHyA)