# Typescript is NOT complaining about type error in Object Spread Syntax

Tags: typescript

The following Snippets should throw a typescript error, but it's not complaining in any snippet when the object spread syntax is used.

Please note, that a added a typo for the `address` property on purpose for this test.

### Snippet A.1. - not throwing error

```
interface TestType {
  company?: string;
  address?: string;
}

function testFunction(): TestType {
  const cond = true;
  const testDto = {
    ...(cond ? { company: '' } : {}),
    ...(cond ? { addressss: '' } : {}),
  };
  return testDto;
}
```

### Snippet A.2. - not throwing error

```
interface TestType {
  company?: string;
  address?: string;
}

function testFunction() {
  const cond = true;
  const testDto:TestType = {
    ...(cond ? { company: '' } : {}),
    ...(cond ? { addressss: '' } : {}),
  };
  return testDto;
}
```

### Snippet A.3. - not throwing error

```
interface TestType {
  company?: string;
  address?: string;
}

function testFunction() {
  const cond = true;
  const testDto= {
    ...(cond ? { company: '' } : {}),
    ...(cond ? { addressss: '' } : {}),
  };
  return testDto as TestType;
}
```

### Snippet B.1. - successfully throwing error

This Snippet is successfully throwing a typescript error, because I removed the object spread syntax and put the interface definition right after the constant name.

```
interface TestType {
  company?: string;
  address?: string;
}

function testFunction() {
  const cond = true;
  const testDto:TestType = {
    company: '',
    addressss: '',
  };
  return testDto;
}
```

### Snippet B.2. - not throwing error

This Snippet is still not throwing a typescript error, even if object spread syntax is removed, but the interface is defined in the function return type.

```
interface TestType {
  company?: string;
  address?: string;
}

function testFunction():TestType {
  const cond = true;
  const testDto = {
    company: '',
    addressss: '',
  };
  return testDto;
}
```

I also tested in an online typescript editor to exclude potential issues with my environment.

Can somebody help me understand what's going on? Also, could someone provide an example with a solution that detects misspellings when the object spread syntax is used?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Probably relevant: [Eslint not complaining about properties that do not exist when using spread operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75802106)

Comment: fyi `as` tells typescript to completely ignore itself - so avoid that when possible

Comment: @VLAZ

`satisfies` is the answer. Thanks a lot! However, I still don't understand why typescript would not complain about unknown properties, anyways.

Comment: It is a typescript issue disucessed here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32495

Answer (score 1):

You declared `company` & `address` as optional (by using `?:`).
So typescript is ok to that your return object hasn't those properties.
This should throw an error:

```
interface TestType {
  company: string; // I removed the questions mark
  address: string;
}

function testFunction(): TestType {
  const cond = true;
  const testDto = {
    ...(cond ? { company: '' } : {}),
    ...(cond ? { address: '' } : {}),
  };
  return testDto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! However, I don't see why Typescript wouldn't check for misspellings. `addresssssss` is not a known property of the interface and therefore should throw an error.

Also, it indeed successfully throws an error in the following Snippet:

  const testDto:TestType = {
    company: '',
    addressss: '',
  };

Which is also (at least in my point of view) a proof that it should throw an error.

Comment: When you define the type of a variable typescript expects exact type matching (typescript will work like the set theory), so the example will have an error (address is not defined in TestType). Still, if you specify the type of the return type in the function signature, your example would be accepted by TS because it's a subset of the TestType with an additional property.  
I hope that I explained that properly.

Comment: That helps a bit, thanks a lot. Still, I don't understand why typescript accepts a subset of the TestType with an additional property when the return type of the function is declared. In my understanding it doesn't make sense to allow unknown properties, when the return type is defined. This behavior could potentially allow many typos. I'd love to understand it better though, if you have enough energy left for another explanation.

Also I noticed that ts generally seems to lose type checking with object spread syntax, see: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32495

Comment: @christian because an object with an extra property still satisfies the requirements of the interface.