# TypeScript not erroring using spread syntax

Tags: typescript

How come TS is not showing an error in strict mode with this code?

```
export interface Type {
    prop1: number;
}

const f1 = <T>(fn: (value: T) => T): void => console.log('this is called');

f1((value: Type) =>  ({ ...value, nonExistent: 4}));
```

Shouldn't the compiler show an error because the returning type is not `Type` when adding the `nonExistent` property?

Comment: Related: [TypeScript not complaining about properties that do not exist when using spread operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75802106)

Comment: Also, the return value from ` f1` *is* `Type`. The fact that it has extra properties doesn't disqualify it. A dog is still an animal, even if it has a `bark`. TS type system is structural - as long as the object fulfils anything in the interface it *is* that thing. Extra properties aren't considered. You can't access them normally. `animal.bark` will give you an error.

Comment: that's not always true, is it? If I'd do this I'd get an error: a: Type = { prop1: 3, other: 45 }

Comment: There are [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#excess-property-checks) but only in basically three places. And only if you *directly* use an object, not if you use a variable https://tsplay.dev/mpoggN

Comment: See also [What is structural typing?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) in the TS FAQ

Comment: Ok, I see, thanks! It's quite counter intuitive from my point of view.